# HTML lang tag - Screen Reader text-to-speech

Tags: html, lang

i have a website which is written in German language. Inside I have some words like Tag which should be spoken by screen reader in there native language. My Problem is that I don´t want for every word like "tag" use

```
<span lang="en">Tag</span>>
```

Is there a way to define this like a Dictionary for special words which should spoken in English?

Comment: Don't understand what you're trying to achieve exactly...

Comment: Everytime the word Tag shall be spoken in english not in german by a screenreader. But if i have to use the lang-tag everytime it is much work for me  to rewrite it in the html code.

Comment: sorry, man, not much more clear... to start with, what do you use for screenreader? what does it require? are you using pure html or maybe another language too like php...?

Comment: OK, for first it should be for every screenreader. The Problem is that normaly the Screenreader read the german word "Tag" its in English "Day" but the SR should read everytime the english word "Tag" because it doesn´t make sense for german when the Screenreader read the german Word for "day". So I want that I define only one time that the word tag should be spoken in english not in german. I don´t know how I could it explain in an other way. By the way I use Javascript too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no other way to declare the language of individual words than wrapping each word in an element and setting the `lang` attribute on it. You might be able to generate such markup programmatically, but this depends on your data, the exact definition of how words should be marked up, and the technologies available.

On the other hand, speech browsers often ignore `lang` attributes or implement them oddly. Switching to a different language in the midst of a sentence might produce something disruptive. So do some testing to check whether the `lang` markup really helps, before spending time and effort on generating it.